# Get variable from include

Tags: php, scope

I have four files: functions.php, lang.php, init.php and index.php.

**functions.php**

```
function loadLanguage()
{
    include_once("lang.php");
}
```

**lang.php**

```
$LANG = array(
    "SOMETEXT" => "This is a random text"
);
```

**init.php**

```
include_once("functions.php");
loadLanguage();
```

**index.php**

```
include_once("init.php");
echo $LANG["SOMETEXT"];
```

I get this:

> Undefined variable $LANG.

I found a solution in init.php: `$LANG = loadLanguage();`, but I don't want to use this. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

Because you have this line in a function

```
include_once("lang.php");
```

the variables defined in `lang.php` are only defined in the function `loadLanguage`. When you try to access those variables as globals later, they are undefined. If you need them to be global, make them global; otherwise, you have to return them from a function or pass them around in some other way.

---

Put differently, your code is equivalent to this:

```
// include_once("init.php");
// does this:
    // include_once("functions.php");
    // does this:
        function loadLanguage()
        {
            // include_once("lang.php");
            // does this:
                $LANG = array(
                    "SOMETEXT" => "This is a random text"
                );
        }

    loadLanguage();
echo $LANG["SOMETEXT"];
```

Stripping out all of the includes, you would get:

```
function loadLanguage()
{
    $LANG = array(
        "SOMETEXT" => "This is a random text"
    );
}

loadLanguage();
echo $LANG["SOMETEXT"];
```

Which makes it easy to see that `$LANG` is actually a local variable in the scope of `loadLanguage`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a hack, but you can declare `$LANG` as `global` inside of `loadLanguage()` and then accomplish what you need. Ed Cottrell's answer describes why your approach won't work.

**init.php**

```
<?php

function loadLanguage()
{
    global $LANG;
    include_once("lang.php");
}

var_dump($LANG);

loadLanguage();

var_dump($LANG);
```

**Output**

```
~$ php init.php
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: LANG in /Users/Josh/init.php on line 9
NULL
array(1) {
  ["s"]=>
  string(6) "string"
}
```